# Is there any way to change object's restitution coefficient in processing(with fisica)?

Tags: processing

I'm making a program that one ball collide with a obstacle.
I want to set restitution coefficient of obstacle individually.
What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

It depends what the obstacle is (your question doesn't clarify that).

If the obstacle is a subclass of `FBody` (e.g. `FCircle`, `FBox`, `FLine`, etc.) you can simply call [`setResitution()`](http://www.ricardmarxer.com/fisica/reference/fisica/FBody.html#setRestitution(float)).

If the obstacle is the `FWorld` you can use [`setEdgesRestitution()`](http://www.ricardmarxer.com/fisica/reference/fisica/FWorld.html#setEdgesRestitution(float))

Also check out **Processing > Examples > Contributed Libraries > Fisica > Restitutions**

Comment: Oh! I thought function <setEdgeRestitution()> is for edge of window, but it wasn't!
And I didn't know that class <FBody> exist...
Maybe I can try that way!

Comment: You should share the your attempt in code: it will make it a lot easier for others to visualise and provide more accurate feedback.